# ggplot2: scale_*_time formats incorrectly

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

**Goal**

Use `ggplot2::scale_*_time` to format a time axis in a particular way (with the most recent version of `ggplot2`).

**Minimal Reprex**

```
# Example data
tib1 <- tibble::tibble(
    x = 1:10,
    y = lubridate::as.duration(seq(60, 600, length.out = 10))
)
```

Using `ggplot2::scale_*_time` with `format = "%R"` doesn't work - the axes are formatted using `%H:%M:%S`:

```
# This doesn't work
ggplot2::ggplot(tib1) +
    ggplot2::geom_point(ggplot2::aes(x,y)) +
    ggplot2::scale_y_time(labels = scales::date_format(format = "%R"))
```

However, I can add the time variable (`y`) to an arbitrary date, and then format the resultant `datetime` object:

```
# This works
tib2 <- tib1 %>%
    dplyr::mutate(z = lubridate::ymd_hms("2000-01-01 00:00:00") + y)

ggplot2::ggplot(tib2) +
    ggplot2::geom_point(ggplot2::aes(x,z)) +
    ggplot2::scale_y_datetime(labels = scales::date_format(format = "%R"))
```

Obviously, I'd prefer not to add an arbitrary date to my times to get the axis to format correctly (which I had to do until `ggplot2::scale_*_time` was introduced, but hope to avoid now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your durations get silently converted to an `hms` object, which are always displayed as `hh:mm:ss` (i.e. `hms`). `scales::date_format` uses `format` which doesn't do anything with `hms` objects, other than converting them to character vectors. Ideally, it would be easy to have a proper `format.hms` method that can control how much is shown, but as it stands `hms:::format.hms` doesn't actually take any `format` argument.

A solution is to simply delete the first three characters:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(tib1) +
  ggplot2::geom_point(ggplot2::aes(x,y)) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_time(labels = function(x) substring(x, 4))
```